# Divide a seq of pairs into two lists?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Assume I have a `Seq` or pairs(or tuples):

```
val s = Seq((1, "1"), (2, "2"), (3, "3"))
```

How could I do:

```
val (ints, strs) = (s.map(_._1), s.map(_._2))
```

Without iterating the Seq twice?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here it is

```
val (ints, strs) = seq.unzip
```

Comment: Didn't expect it... great!